# Why do you say "in diesem Sinne" if "Sinne" is a feminine noun?

Tags: grammar, gender, dative

The [LEO page for "Sinne"](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=en&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=sinne) shows that the noun Sinne is a **feminine** noun, yet is used in the phrase "**in diesem Sinne**".

Shouldn't that be "**in dieser Sinne**"?

Comment: related: [Wie wird die Redewendung “wie es im Buche steht” grammatisch gebildet?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/4579/1224)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm sure this is a misunderstanding.

Two points:

The "-e"-ending appears to be a relict from times when German still formed the Dative with a suffix. It's retained in phrases like "im Jahre xxxx", in quotations like "dem Manne kann geholfen werden". Perfectly correct, if not extremely common.

Secondly: Where does it say feminine on the LEO page?

Edit: Em1 pointed out the possible reason for the confusion... remember: the article "die" is used for the plural of all nouns, regardless of their gender.

Comment: To 2nd: perhaps *wits - die Sinne*.

Comment: ... which is plural, just like in English. "Die Sinne" can refer to either the five physical senses or the consciousness (cf. the English "insensible" - in Jane Austen's time a synonym for unconscious) :)

Comment: Yes, I thought "die Sinne" meant that the noun "Sinne" was singular and feminine, thanks.

Comment: Well, it *is* confusing if you didn't grow up with it :) - very understandable!

Answer (score 14):

Your confusion is effected through the plural form: [*der Sinn*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Sinn), *die Sinne*.

*In diesem Sinne* is **only one** Sinn, not many *Sinne*.

The dative of *der Sinn* is built up with *dem* and not *der* as in feminine nouns.

So it is correct to say *In diesem Sinne*.

(Regarding the -e take notice of Mac's answer)