# Wie wird die Redewendung  "wie es im Buche steht" grammatisch gebildet?

Tags: grammar, idiom, dative

Ich habe ziemlich oft folgende Redewendung gehört:

> Es ist ..., wie es im Buche steht.

Ich glaube ich verstehe diesen Ausdruck - es geht darum, dass etwas ganz typisch ist.

Ich frage mich, was für eine grammatische Form *"im Buche"* ist. Heute würde man doch *"im Buch"* sagen.

Im [Wiktionary-Artikel](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aDeutsch/Redewendungen_nach_Herkunft#Bibel) über Redewendungen nach ihrer Herkunft ist ein Zusammenhang mit der Bibel erwähnt. Deshalb neige ich dazu, dass es sich um eine veraltete Form handelt.

---

I have heard quite often the idiom:

> Es ist ..., wie es im Buche steht.

I believe I understand this idiom - it means that something is typical.

I would like to ask what grammar form *"im Buche"* is, since today I would say *"im Buch"* instead.

This idiom is mentioned in [Wiktionary-article](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aDeutsch/Redewendungen_nach_Herkunft#Bibel) on idioms by origin in connection with the Bible.  So I guess it might be some kind of obsolete form, which is not used in today's German.

Comment: related: [Why do you say “in diesem Sinne” if “Sinne” is a feminine noun?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/3868/1224)

Comment: Just some translation help: The German "wie es im Buche steht" is a pretty direct cognate to the English "a textbook case".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dativ#Dativ-e)  this is called "Dativ-e":

> Der Dativ Singular wurde früher bei Hauptwörtern, die im Genitiv
>   Singular auf -es enden können, also bei stark gebeugten männlichen und
>   sächlichen Hauptwörtern, mit der Endung -e gekennzeichnet. Diese Form
>   ist heute veraltet und wird in der Gegenwartssprache üblicherweise
>   nicht mehr gesetzt. Häufige Ausnahmen sind feststehende Wendungen wie
>   beispielsweise „in diesem Sinne“, „im Hause“ (als Briefanschrift),
>   „Warnung vor dem Hunde“ oder „im Jahre“. Auch kann das Dativ-e aus
>   stilistischen und rhythmischen Gründen weiterhin gesetzt werden.

For more information you might want to read [this paper](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/downloads/allgemeine_downloads/Vorbildliche_Hauptseminararbeiten/Phraseologische_Verwendung_des_Dativ-e.pdf). It states that the use of "Dativ-e" in common usage "bis zum 16. Jahrhundert im Oberdeutschen beinahe
vollständig, größtenteils im Westmitteldeutschen und partiell im Ostmitteldeutschen" came to a standstill. Furthermore, the use of "Dativ-e" in idioms is analyzed (2.2, some nice diagrams) and reasons are given why the usage in idioms is still common (rhyme, style, easier pronunciation, see paragraph 3).

Concerning your example the author researched that in the 20th century in the majority of cases (77,1%) the idiom was used with the "Dativ-e".