# Apostrophe in “Ruh’” from Goethes “Wandrers Nachtlied II”

Tags: history, spelling, punctuation, apostrophe

I’ve been looking at early (e.g. 1827) published editions of Goethes *Wandrers Nachtlied II* (also known as *Ein Gleiches*), and I don’t understand the significance of the apostrophe after *Ruh* in line 2:

> Ueber allen Gipfeln
>   Ist Ruh’,
>   In allen Wipfeln
>   Spürest du
>   Kaum einen Hauch;
>   Die Vögelein schweigen im Walde.
>   Warte nur, balde
>   Ruhest du auch.

There are a few differences between these early editions and most of the current ones I’ve seen, but except for *Ruh’* (which I’ve usually seen as *Ruh,* sans apostrophe, in modern editions), these make sense to me as minor spelling/orthography changes (e.g. *Ueber* vs. *Über, Wandrers* vs. *Wanderers*).

I don’t understand what the meaning of the apostrophe is in the earlier version. Does it signify an omitted word-ending, e.g. affecting case? The modern apostrophe-less *Ruh* seems to make perfect (and very uncomplicated) grammatical sense, so I don’t understand why some versions print *Ruh’* with an apostrophe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you omit a letter (very often an *e* at the end of an word), you mark this with an apostrophe:

> Ruh’ = Ruhe (calm/peace)
>   Wo ich geh’ und steh’ = Wo ich gehe und stehe.

But very often this apostrophe is taken as optional, so it is omitted too. But when being strict this is not correct:

> Ruh = Ruh’ = Ruhe
>   Wo ich geh und steh = Wo ich geh’ und steh’ = Wo ich gehe und stehe.

Comment: Actually, when taken strictly, the apostrophe is **wrong** according to the 2006 spelling rules. It is only allowed when a shortened form is _schwer lesbar oder missverständlich_ (§ 96 (2)) or _undurchsichtig_ (§ 97), which is hardly the case here.

Comment: I think this makes sense. (Certainly it made me suddenly realize, after having been thinking about this for some time, that there _is_ usually an `-e` on `Ruh(e)`.) Is the reason for omitting the final `-e` essentially just poetic (e.g. for meter's sake)? Or would this ever happen in prose?

Comment: It's purely for meter's sake. Sometimes, an -e is also added (*Im Haus**e** muss beginnen // was leuchten soll im Vaterland*), and that is also sometimes done to add extra gravitas to rhetoric (In diesem unserem Land**e**). None of these devices enjoy a high reputation in contemporary poetry anymore.

Comment: @microtherion: The dative _-e_ was considered obligatory until not so long ago. Certainly Goethe and his contemporaries would have felt that _im Haus_ was missing an _-e_. See http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7906 and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4579

Answer (score 1):

Hubert’s answer nicely explains the pre-reformed orthographic situation. Anything pre-1996 is likely to follow one of the two former standards (or no standard at all) and would therefore prefer to use an apostrophe here to replace the missing *e*.

Following the reform, a large number of formerly required apostrophes were either disallowed completely or made optional. Compare the [official rules](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) (translated by me):

> § 96: An apostrophe is written in three types of cases:
>
> These include:
>
> (1) Proper nouns whose nominative end in an *s*-sound (*-s, -ss, -ß, -z, -tz, -x, -ce*) are given an apostrophe in the genitive case if they do not have an article, a possessive pronoun or similar with them.
>
> - *Aristoteles’ Schriften*
>
> E1: But: *Die Schriften des Aristoteles*
>
> E2: The apostrophe is also used if the *-s, -z, -x* of the nominative is silent: Cannes’ Filmfestspiele.
>
> (2) Words with omissions that would be hard to read or misunderstandable without the apostrophe:
>
> - *Das Wasser rauscht’, das Wasser schwoll*
>
> (3) Words with inside parts omitted as in:
>
> - *D’dorf (= Düsseldorf), Ku’damm (= Kurfürstendamm).
>
> §97: One may write an apostrophe if words of spoken language with omissions are not clear in written language.
>
> - *Der Käpt’n mit’m Fahrrad; Bitte nehmen S’ Platz!*
>
> E: To be distinguished from the apostriophe as omission marker is the occasional use of this punctuation mark to clarify the basic form of a proper noun before the genitive’s ending *-s* or the adjectiv suffix *-sch*
>
> - Carlo’s Taverne, Einstein’sche Relativitätstheorie.

Omitting the final *e* in *Ruhe* does not qualify for any of these cases. The [Duden rules](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph) go into slightly more detail, by also saying which cases can be considered ‘easy to read’:

> 1. An unstressed *-e-* (translator’s note: shwa) in the inside of a word is dropped:
>
>    - Ich wechsle
>    - trockner Boden
> 2. Final *-e* of certain verb forms are dropped:
>
>    - Das hör ich gern.
>    - Ich lass das nicht zu.
>    - Leg den Mantel ab.
> 3. **It is a shortened form of the noun or adjective** (translator’s note: or adverb) **that is in common use:**
>
>    - öd (next to *öde)
>    - Bursch (next to *Bursche*)
>    - trüb (next to *trübe*)
>    - heut (next to *heute*)
> 4. Phrases which make use of an uninflected adjective or pronoun:
>
>    - um gut Wetter bitten
>    - ruhig Blut bewahren
>    - Wir wollen sein ein einzig Volk von Brüdern …

I boldfaced the case **3** which is relevant here: Everybody would understand that *Ruh* is missing an *e* at the end, so the apostrophe is not required by today’s orthography.