# Wo kommt der Ausdruck "Im Laufe" her?

Tags: grammatical-case, standard-german, expression

Das Verb ist laufen, der Nomen ist der Lauf (die Läufe, Pl.).

Also warum schreibt man "Im Laufe des letzten Jahres" anstatt "Im Lauf des letzten Jahres".

Wo kommt "Laufe" her und warum füge man dieses "e" am Ende hinzu?

Comment: Ähnlich: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4579/wie-wird-die-redewendung-wie-es-im-buche-steht-grammatisch-gebildet/4580#4580

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Laufe' ist die veraltete Form des Dativs von 'Lauf'. Diese veraltete Form des Dativs findet sich noch bei vielen Worten, insbesondere in festen Redewendungen wie hier z.B. "Im Laufe eines Jahres". Die andere Form "Im Lauf eines Jahres" ist durchaus auch korrekt - wenn auch nicht ganz so geläufig.

Andere Beispiele:

> Im Zug**e** der Verhandlungen...
> Die Haare zu Berg**e** stehen haben...
> Die Gespräche sind noch im Gang(e).
> Das Kind im Manne
> etc

Siehe bspw. auch [hier](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/fragen/25).

Answer (score 7):

Die Angelegenheit ist tatsächlich andersherum: "Im Laufe" hat kein zusätzliches "e" bekommen, sondern es hat noch ein "e", das in vielen anderen Fällen verlorengegangen ist.

Wenn man beispielsweise auf den [Eintrag für "Lauf" bei Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lauf) schaut, findet man für den Genetiv und den Dativ Singular jeweils zwei Formen:

"des Laufs" und "des Laufes"

sowie

"dem Lauf" und "dem Laufe"

Dabei sind die Formen mit dem zusätzlichen "e" die älteren, die im Alltag meistens nicht mehr verwendet werden. Sie haben sich aber in feststehenden Ausdrücken wie zum Beispiel "im Laufe der Zeit" erhalten. Es gibt aber durchaus auch die Variante "im Lauf der Zeit". Außerhalb solcher feststehenden Ausdrücke verwendet man die Formen mit zusätzlichem "e" beispielsweise, wenn man einen besonders feierlichen Tonfall möchte.